# How can I track usage statistics of iOS today widget?

Tags: ios, iphone

My app has two widgets and I would like to learn how many users activated them in Today's view.

Comment: Hi new member. Without more information what you're exactly trying to do, nobody can answer your question. Please, make sure you've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

If your app also has a server, you could ping your server every now and then with a record of how users are using your app. Alternatively, you could use a service like Google Analytics or Facebook Analytics to keep track of different events in your app.